# Orbeon 4.8 and passing headers to CRUD interface

Tags: orbeon

Is it still possible to send custom headers to a customized CRUD interface? 
I tried all of these with no success: According to logging non of these headers is passed to the interface when opening a form.

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.http.forward-headers"                        value="Orbeon-Client Cookie"/>
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.http.forward-headers.private"                value="Orbeon-Client Cookie"/>
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.xforms.forward-submission-headers"           value="Orbeon-Client Cookie"/>
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.http.forward-cookies"                        value="JSESSIONID MYSAPSSO2 ReferenceCode"/>
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.http.forward-cookies.private"                value="JSESSIONID MYSAPSSO2 ReferenceCode"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

They found the issue and fixed it:  https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2053

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on trying to solve this problem without avail.

(FYI, we are upgrading from 4.5 to 4.8 right now in our test environment and ran into the issue that specified cookies asked to be forwarded in properties-local.xml are do not seem to be honored in the persistence layer).

A few posts I have seen as we are trying to fix this....

http://discuss.orbeon.com/Secure-persistence-API-access-td4659372.html

^ This post seems to indicate that it is broken(?) in 4.8 and will be added back to 4.9? 
(Looking at the code for FormRunnerPersistenceProxy.scala doesn't seem to indicate this thou?)

http://discuss.orbeon.com/oxf-http-forward-cookies-issue-in-case-of-invalid-JSESSIONID-td4658705.html

^ Different but similar issue

Comment: I grapped the github repo and compiled the master branch (4.9pre) which fixed the error for us. Still had to change 1 line of code due to SAP Netweaver stuff.